# Neos CMS installation 500 error: Specified path not found

Tags: typo3-flow, neoscms

I tried to install **Neos CMS** local under Windows 10 with a Wamp Apache Server. After creating the project with a composer and registering the Vhosts, I tried to run `neos.demo/setup`. Then I get an *500 internal server error* with the message *"Specified path not found”*, for more information, take a look at the screenshot.

I checked the solutions for the **exception code 1355480641**, but nothing can solve my problem.

Thanks for your recommendations!

[image: Screenshot showing the error message]

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error in the current version of Neos CMS (v4.1). The solution to the problem was for me:

- Adjust Configuration/Settings.yaml with the php.exe path (which you already did)
- Launch an administrator cmd
- Go to the Neos CMS directory
- Run *flow flow:core:compile*
- Run *flow flow:cache:warmup*

Now I could access Neos with XAMPP.

All credit for this answer goes to the following post: https://discuss.neos.io/t/running-neos-flow-on-windows-10-success/2752

Answer (score 0):

do you have set `Neos.Flow.core.phpBinaryPathAndFilename` in  `Configuration/Settings.yaml` to the correct php.exe binary path?

Comment: sure. in the documentation is a notice regarding to windows. so i did this before trying to run the installation. i think it's a windows problem. because while developing with laravel under windows 10, i got similiar errors.

Comment: you can try to start the subprocess from command line " FLOW_CONTEXT=Production ./flow neos.flow:core:compile" and check the stacktrace?

Comment: It gives me the same error in my CMD-Tool "System can't find the specified path".

Answer (score 0):

This is not an actual solution, this is more of an alternative.

I was having troubles installing neos on windows 10 as well (not the same as you though), a really nice solution that I would recommend as alternative to wamp is [bitnami-neos](https://bitnami.com/stack/neos/installer).

Comment: Hi, thanks four your reply. I know the bitnami-neos installer. but the problem is the same..